# Jquery CSS display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm really new to Jquery so I really need a some help from you guys.

I have created a button, when clicked a pop up menu will appear. Now I have created a script, what it does is when that button is clicked the sideshow on the site background will be hidden (this is to make the pop up menu much smoother), my question is after a user closes down the pop up menu, how can I reshow the hidden slideshow again , I believe it has something to do with this code `onHide: function()`

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.menubutton').click(function(){
        jQuery("#slideshow").css({"display":"none"});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the manual yet? http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 3):

To show and hide alternatively use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
jQuery("#slideshow").toggle()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6us29/)

To Hide an element use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

```
jQuery("#slideshow").hide()
```

To Display a hidden an element use [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
jQuery("#slideshow").show()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,I checked the fiddle demo so the user has to again click on that button to hide a div, the thing is this is a pop up, the user can click anywhere on the screen to close that pop up

Answer (score 1):

I believe [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is what you are after:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.menubutton').click(function () {
        jQuery('#slideshow').toggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QGdLw/1/